# How to smoothly rasterize PDF using the API?

Tags: go, imagemagick

I'd like to rasterize a PDF source (in this case to PNG, 500x500 pixels) using [these golang bindings](https://github.com/gographics/imagick) for ImageMagick6. On the CLI, I can do this using

```
convert -density 5000 -define psd:fit-page=500x test.pdf -resize 500x test.png
```

which results in a smoothly rendered image.

What I'm failing to do right now is to produce something similar using the API: either the resulting image has scaled pixels or is blurry and has a size 500x500 pixels, or it's in the "original" size.

Here's a minimum snippet of my playground code:

```
package main

import "gopkg.in/gographics/imagick.v2/imagick"

func main() {
    imagick.Initialize()
    defer imagick.Terminate()
    mw := imagick.NewMagickWand()
    defer mw.Destroy()

    mw.SetImageResolution(5000,5000)
    mw.SetOption("psd:fit-page", "500x")

    mw.ReadImage("test.pdf")
    mw.ResizeImage(500, 500, imagick.FILTER_POINT, 1)
    mw.SetIteratorIndex(0) // This being the page offset
    mw.SetImageFormat("png")
    mw.WriteImage("test.png")
}
```

I got confused by *density*, *image size*, *image resolution* and *canvas size* I guess. How is it meant to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GO version of the `convert` command is missing the "density" argument. Replacing the call to `SetImageResolution` with one to `SetOption` and using a filter to smooth out the edges results in a smooth image:

```golang
package main

import "gopkg.in/gographics/imagick.v2/imagick"

func main() {
    imagick.Initialize()
    defer imagick.Terminate()
    mw := imagick.NewMagickWand()
    defer mw.Destroy()

    mw.SetOption("density", "5000")
    mw.SetOption("psd:fit-page", "500x")

    mw.ReadImage("test.pdf")

    mw.ResizeImage(500, 500, imagick.FILTER_LAGRANGE, 1)
    mw.SetIteratorIndex(0) // This being the page offset
    mw.SetImageFormat("png")
    mw.WriteImage("test.png")
}
```

Comment: Lol. I guess I did too much playing around that I forgot to add the Density. Thanks!